# What is the minimal GDScript equivalent of Python websocket client code?

Tags: python, websocket, echo, gdscript

I'm attempting to program a simple turn-based game in Godot which relies on a Python websocket server for rules and state updates. To that end, I'm trying to make a simple prototype where I can input text into a Godot client, send it to the websocket, and receive some data back - an 'echo' configuration.

I have server code outlined already:

```py
# server.py

import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65432

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

I could write a client in Python that sends data and receives the echo, but my efforts to do the same in Godot are sluggish at best. What might the minimum GDScript file for a client look like? Where should I look for tutorials on this sort of thing?

I've looked at the Godot Official documentation in search of answers, then tutorials online. Maybe it's just my search engine acting up, but I haven't found anything that at once addresses my question and explains it in basic terms.

Comment: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/networking/websocket.html#html5-and-websocket

Did you found this in the godot docs? It's basically all you are asking for. Or is something unclear?

Comment: @Bugfish I did see that; the code doesn't work for my version of Godot (4.2) due to `Error at (4, 1): Unexpected identifier in class body` - then, when that error's fixed, `Error at (7, 15): Identifier "WebSocketClient" not declared in the current scope.` It's not up-to-date for Godot 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Godot 4.2 WebSocketClient seems to not exist anymore, but in the editor I found the class [WebSocketPeer](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.2/classes/class_websocketpeer.html) with an example. I extended the example to show how to send a message to the socket server.

```
extends Node

# The URL we will connect to
@export var websocket_url = "ws://localhost:8080"

# Our WebSocketClient instance
var socket = WebSocketPeer.new()

func _ready():
    var err =  socket.connect_to_url(websocket_url)
    if err != OK:
        print("Unable to connect")
        set_process(false)
    else:
        print("connected")

func _process(delta):
    socket.poll()
    var state = socket.get_ready_state()
    if state == WebSocketPeer.STATE_OPEN:
        while socket.get_available_packet_count():
            _on_message_received(socket.get_packet())
    elif state == WebSocketPeer.STATE_CLOSING:
        # Keep polling to achieve proper close.
        pass
    elif state == WebSocketPeer.STATE_CLOSED:
        var code = socket.get_close_code()
        var reason = socket.get_close_reason()
        _on_closed(code, reason)

func _on_message_received(packet: PackedByteArray):
    var message = packet.get_string_from_utf8()
    print("WebSocket message received: %s" % message)

func _on_closed(code, reason):
    print("WebSocket closed with code: %d, reason %s. Clean: %s" % [code, reason, code != -1])
    set_process(false) # Stop processing.

func _send_message(message : String):
    var state = socket.get_ready_state()
    if state == WebSocketPeer.STATE_OPEN:
        socket.send_text(message)
```

Basically it's similar to the WebSocketClient, but without the signals. In the process you poll the socket and check the current state. If it's open you get the available packets.

Same for sending. If you directly want to send a string you can use the send_text function as in the example. To send a byte array you can use send.

Comment: Thank you, this is a fantastic help. I'm now having difficulty getting the client to actually connect to the Python websocket. I keep getting the error `WebSocket closed with code: -1, reason . Clean: false`. The code for sending data to the websocket executes, but the socket doesn't seem to be accepting the data at all.

Comment: Do you get the error if you send data, or does the connection break on it's own? Because the socket is not cleanly closed I assume something somewhere breaks. You should try to get more logs from your server too, to see if the error lies there somewhere.

Comment: The connection breaks on its own. Even though the client states that it has connected to the server, the server never acknowledges a connection.

Comment: I am not familiar with python and don't have good internet right now, cause I am on the train, but you could try to use the https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ library instead of the plain socket library.

Comment: Sorry for the wait. The code provided at that link for the `echo` server worked perfectly for me. I can't wait to further incorporate `asyncio` into my project. Thank you so much!